# Selenium headless chromedriver unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Helllo everyone, I'm on raspberry pi with no gui and I'm trying to use Selenium chromedriver in headless mode. I keep getting an exception saying that driver is unable to locate what i'm searching for. The fact is that without headless mode I have no problem and my code works fine.

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080');
        self.drivers = []
        for j in range(2):
            self.drivers.append(webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"))


    def clearCache(self, index):
        self.drivers[index].get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            settings = self.drivers[index].find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

The error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//settings-ui"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.187)
```

**EDIT**
I tried taking a screenshot

```
self.drivers[index].get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
self.drivers[index].get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
```

and I get a blank image.

**EDIT2**
I am noticing that it seems to have troubles getting settings page

```
self.drivers[index].get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
```

because elements searched in other pages can be found with no exception. I just needed to go to the settings in order to delete the cache (because my bot will loop refreshing a page each time deleting the cache).
The strange thing is that without headless mode, all works fine and `self.drivers[index].get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')` does not end in a blank screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure it is only headless mode settings problem? Can you share the page you are testing?

Comment: If I comment `options.add_argument('--headless')` my code works fine. The page in which I cannot find what without headless mode I can find is `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add the below arguments. Alternatively You may add the URL onetime manually by joining to Internat Option->Security-> Trusted Sites-> add the URL.

```
--allow-running-insecure-content
```

Comment: Did you try adding it in trusted sites

Comment: Sorry from which do I neet to add it? Because isn't right that each time I open chrome with webdriver it opens a "virgin" instance of chrome?

Comment: Thats because SSL certificate issue i believe.  Open Internet Explorer-> go to InternetOptions->Security->Trusted Sites->then Add the URL which you wanted to open

Comment: Also in Chrome browser-go to Settings->PrivacyAndSecurity->Select Insecure content as Allow

Comment: If  you still face issue try to use https in the URL instead of http.

Comment: The problem is not on a web url. The error happens when trying to get `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`

Comment: but why do you need to clear browsing data everytime. Do you need to clear cookies?

Comment: I need to clear cache because I need to keep refreshing the same page within 10secs and I want to be sure browser won't load a cached one each time